# in-app billing with phonegap for android app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, billing

I am developing an android phonegap application and I want to use in app billing in it. I installed the [phonegap billing plugin](https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling/blob/master/v3/) and it works perfectly. Can you help me make it work correct with a link.

For example, here is the script code:

```
<script >
function successHandler (result) {
    var strResult = "";
    if(typeof result === 'object') {
        strResult = JSON.stringify(result);
    } else {
        strResult = result;
    }
    alert("SUCCESS: \r\n"+strResult );
}

function errorHandler (error) {
    alert("ERROR: \r\n"+error );
}

// Click on init button
function init(){
    // Initialize the billing plugin
    inappbilling.init(successHandler, errorHandler, {showLog:true});
}

// Click on purchase button
function buy(){
    // make the purchase
    inappbilling.buy(successHandler, errorHandler, "good_id");
}

// Click on ownedProducts button
function ownedProducts(){
    // Initialize the billing plugin
    inappbilling.getPurchases(successHandler, errorHandler);
}

// Click on Consume purchase button
function consumePurchase(){
    inappbilling.consumePurchase(successHandler, errorHandler, "good_id");
}

// Click on subscribe button
function subscribe(){
    // make the purchase
    inappbilling.subscribe(successHandler, errorHandler,"good_id");
}

// Click on Query Details button
function getDetails(){
    // Query the store for the product details
    inappbilling.getProductDetails(successHandler, errorHandler, "good_id");
}

// Click on Get Available Products button
function getAvailable(){
    // Get the products available for purchase.
    inappbilling.getAvailableProducts(successHandler, errorHandler);
}
</script>
```

And i need it to work with for example -

```
<a href="good.html" id='good' data-ignore="true">Good</a>
```

Thats after clicking on a link first of all i ll be able to pay before linking to a page.
Thanks. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understood what you want, your english is worst than mine. But if you just want to launch a purchase when clicking and after redirect, you may use onclick event and window.location.replace :

```
<a href="good.html" id='good' data-ignore="true" onclick="buy()" >Good</a>

// Click on purchase button
function buy(){
// make the purchase
    inappbilling.buy(successHandler, errorHandler, "good_id");
    return false;
}
```

and then add window.location.replace('yourlinkpage'); on your successHandler

But maybe an input submit should be more appropriate?